# requireJs can not find modules when running on travis

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine, travis-ci

I am trying to use requireJs first time in my javascript project. i have written my test cases in jasmine and using grunt to run them. everything is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy the same on travis. requireJs is not able to resolve module dependencies and throwing errors.

```
  Error: scripterror: Illegal path or script error: ['ListModel']
```

project Url: https://github.com/metanitesh/Js.jQuery.metaList

travis build: https://travis-ci.org/metanitesh/Js.jQuery.metaList

Comment: It looks like you solved the problem and your build is now passing.  Would you mind answering your own question?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using mac for development, and I named my files in camelCase notation. I guess the problem was with case insensitive nature of mac osX, travis was not able to read these files.

I renamed all the files in lowercase and it's working fine.